# omp parallel write in random order

Tags: c++, openmp, rcpp, armadillo

I am using omp to write in array something like

```
    mat out(numGenes,8);
    pragma omp parallel for  schedule(static)
        for (int gene2 = 0; gene2< numGenes; gene2++)        
        {
            scna2 = scnaq.col(gene2);
            out(gene2, 0) = myRanksum(scna2(grp1), scna2(grp2));
            out(gene2, 1) = myRanksum(scna2(grp1), scna2(grp3));
            out(gene2, 2) = myRanksum(scna2(grp2), scna2(grp3));
    }
```

however, I found that the output written in variable out is in random order. I mean out(1,) does not have output corresponding to "gene2=1". I thought each job are scheduled in random order but out is written in current indices of public array. I am using http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html with Rcpp ( http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I figure out reason of the problem. The gene2 variable is declared inside pragma, therefore its a private variable for each thread and writing at random place in out variable. The correct way would be to declare gene2 variable outside pragma.

Comment: OpenMP will make `gene2` private even if you declare it outside of the parallel region because automatically makes the iterator of a parallel for private.